# Object Oriented plugin, add action and variables

Tags: plugin-development, oop

I'm developing a plugin using the WordPress Plugin Boilerplate and am after hitting a wall.

I need to hook into when a custom post type is published (as in the user hits publish) and when its updated.

I'm fairly sure I should be looking at Post Status Transitions https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions but I'm having a bit of trouble getting this to work in an object oriented way.

So I've added the action like this (rest of the class omitted):

```
private function define_admin_hooks() {
    $this->loader->add_action( 'transition_post_status', $plugin_admin, 'publish_my_plugin_post_type' );
}
```

and here's the the method called:

```
public function publish_my_plugin_post_type($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    //do stuff here
}
```

When I try this out I get warnings that I'm missing arguments for the method publish_my_plugin_post_type. In a non OOP world these arguments are available. How can I make these variables available and still use OOP? They are variables supplied by WordPress see below:

> When do_action() is called for transition_post_status, three arguments are passed to it: $new_status, $old_status and the $post object. Therefore, these are also available to be used in the callback function.

Cheers!

Comment: In your method `publish_my_plugin_post_type` it has three arguments.I think we need to explicitly mention 3 arguments while hooking into action `add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'publish_my_plugin_post_type', 10, 3 );`

Comment: @bravokeyl Gah! Yep that was it! Thanks for your help!